# Mocking complex objects like selenium webdriver with Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to Mock the selenium web driver.  I use the following code:

```
    public  IWebDriver GetMockDriver()
    {
        this.Mock = new Mock<IWebDriver>();
        return (IWebDriver)this.Mock.Object;            
    }
```

If I'm just accessing driver properties, everything is fine, but when I try to access an object that is part of Driver, eg:

```
             driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

I get back a System.NullReferenceException.

I don't really want/need to track calls that were made to the Mock object, it's more that I want something that implements iWebDriver so I can write my selenium tests using TDD and not having to actually create an instance of a real web driver each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define an implementation on your mock if you want to call a specific member

```
this.Mock.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod()).Returns(someObject);
```

Try some variation on the above. Otherwise your mocked methods will return the defualt data type for the member (probably null)

Comment: Cheers, are you saying that I would also mock the Manage method/class, and the properties that I needed to support?

Comment: Yes, the default mock will be empty, so you have to provide setup for the methods you intend to call